# Unable to animate SVG element's fill-opacity using framer-motion useScroll

Tags: reactjs, animation, jsx, framer-motion

The `<rect>`s' `fill-opacity` needs to be animated as a user scrolls through the component. This is a vite react project and as you can check from my code, I'm using `useTransform()` to convert `scrollYProgress` values to the required opacity values. There are no warnings/errors in the console and all the framer-motion stuff seems to be compliant with the docs. I've omitted irrelevant code, here:

**Please note:** I'm using Sass and CSS modules in my project, hence all the weird `styles.className` and `id`s. Also, `fillOpacity` is JSX syntax (as opposed to the regular `fill-opacity`).

```
 // Implementing onScroll mask opacity manipulation:
  const svgTargetRef = useRef();
  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
    target: svgTargetRef,
    offset: ["start end", "end start"],
  });

  const opacityVal_One = useTransform(
    scrollYProgress,
    [0, 0.5, 0.65, 1],
    ["0", "0", "1", "1"]
  );
```

JSX:

```
<div ref={svgTargetRef} className={styles.projectBody}>
      <svg
        id={`path-${index}-One`}
        viewBox="0 0 220 100"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        style={{ width: "0", height: "0", position: "absolute" }}
      >
        <g fill="white">
          {/* Line 1: */}
          <motion.rect width="20" height="20" fillOpacity={opacityVal_One} />
          <rect x="20" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0.5" />
          <rect x="40" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0.5" />
          <rect x="60" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
          <rect x="80" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0" />
          <rect x="100" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
          <rect x="120" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0.5" />
          <rect x="140" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
          <rect x="160" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0.5" />
          <rect x="180" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="1" />
          <rect x="200" width="20" height="20" fillOpacity="0.5" />
        </g>
      </svg>
      <img
        id={`masked-${index}-One`}
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506399558188-acca6f8cbf41?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2173&q=80"
        alt="Big data"
      />
    </div>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: did u figure out how to do this ?

Comment: Nope. I decided to change the design. But I'd still appreciate a potential solution to the problem.

Comment: what I ended up doing is to conditionally render the rects , it was good enough for our project .

Answer (score 0):

```js
<div ref={svgTargetRef} className={styles.projectBody}>
  <svg
    id={`path-${index}-One`}
    viewBox="0 0 220 100"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    style={{ width: "0", height: "0", position: "absolute" }}
  >
    <motion.g fill="white" style={{ opacity: opacityVal_One }}>
      {/* Place all your rect elements here */}
      <rect width="20" height="20" />
      <rect x="20" width="20" height="20" />
      <rect x="40" width="20" height="20" />
      {/* ...and so on */}
    </motion.g>
  </svg>
  <img
    id={`masked-${index}-One`}
    src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506399558188-acca6f8cbf41?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2173&q=80"
    alt="Big data"
  />
</div>
```

Comment: I need to animate the opacity of each of the rects separately. It has to happen at varying pace